# Will Oracle 9i OCI driver work with an Oracle 10g server?

Tags: perl, oracle, client, oracle-call-interface

I'm in charge of a Perl application that uses `DBD::Oracle` compiled against a 9.2.0.8 OCI client. This is on a `sun4u` box, albeit with 32-bit binaries. DBD::Oracle is linked against 32-bit OCI libs. We're currently running against a 9i server.

Our DBA team is planning to upgrade the server to 10g, namely 10.2.0.4. I'm faced with two options:

1. Continue using 9i drivers against the new 10g server.
2. **OR**, upgrade our client from 9.2.0.8 to 10.2.0.4 to match the server's version.

For various operational reasons, I'd prefer to go with (**1**) above. However, I am not sure whether a 9i OCI client can work with a 10g Oracle server. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should work. Although, as you might already know, you won't have access to 10g client specific features...

Comment: That's fine, we're not the ones driving the upgrade, so we're not really interested in any of that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe an Oracle 9i driver will work with both 10g and 11g (I know for a fact the Java ones do).

However, your best bet would be to set up a test server/VM with Oracle 10g on it, and test it.